# How to find which user triggered a Pentaho Job from Repository

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a job running in my `Pentaho ETL` server but am unable to figure out which user (i.e. username) had triggered the job. The default logging I can see does not seem to give any details on the user that triggered the job. There must be an easy way here to find this which I am missing, any help would be appreciated.

Details,
I am running `Pentaho EE6.1`

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

By default the username doesn’t show up in the logs, you need to change the format on your log4j.xml for that.

Or enable DB auditing and who ran what and when will be stored in the PRO_AUDIT table.